# Amadeus Point of Interest Search API: Received INVALID DATA RECEIVED with message Sandbox coordinates out of the allowed box

Tags: amadeus

While using Amadeus Java SDK Point of Interest API on test environment, I provided the longitude and latitude received from the city search API, but I got "Invalid Data Received" with detailed message as "Sandbox coordinates out of the allowed box". I am getting similar response while trying directly from Amadeus Self Service API's.

Below is the request URL and response received:-

**Request**

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/pois?latitude=77.10309&longitude=28.5665&radius=1&page%5Blimit%5D=10&page%5Boffset%5D=0

**Response**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "code": 4926,
      "title": "INVALID DATA RECEIVED",
      "detail": "Sandbox coordinates out of the allowed box",
      "source": {
        "parameters": [
          "latitude",
          "longitude",
          "radius"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use the test environment which is free of charge but limited (limited number of calls per API per month and limited set of data as compared to production).

You can find [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection) the data available in test for all our APIs and [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/pois.md) the list of supported cities for Points Of Interest in test.

Note that in addition to the limited number of cities you will get only a maximum of 10 POIs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the reference link.

Comment: second link is incorrect, should be https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/pois.md